# Changing img src with jquery - checking class change

Tags: javascript, html

I have a navbar that's class changes when I scroll down,
I am trying to change my img src when this class changes, I have tried visiting other questions but havent been able to match anything up yet.

im using material design template and my class changes from

```
navbar-transparent navbar-color-on-scroll fixed-top navbar-expand-lg 
navbar-transparent
```

to:

```
navbar-transparent navbar-color-on-scroll fixed-top navbar-expand-lg
```

When it changes I want to change my img src to my black image.

I think part of my problem is my starting class already has the name of the second part?

so this does not work:

the logo is just the black one:

```
    if ($('.navbar').hasClass('navbar-transparent navbar-color-on-scroll fixed-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-transparent')) {
      $('.navbar-brand').attr('src','ZeusLogoWhite.png')

  } else  { ($('.navbar').hasClass('navbar-transparent navbar-color-on-scroll fixed-top navbar-expand-lg')) 
    $('.navbar-brand').attr('src','zeusAssistantBlackLogo.png')
```

The html looks like this:

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-transparent navbar-color-on-scroll fixed-top navbar-expand-lg" color-on-scroll="100" id="sectionsNav">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-translate">
      <!-- Insert logo! -->
        <!-- <a class="navbar-brand" href="https://demos.creative-tim.com/material-kit/index.html">
          Zeus Assistant </a> -->
          <img src="ZeusLogoWhite.png" alt="Thumbnail Image" class="navbar-brand">
```

I think the way the classes change is the wrong way around for me to use?

any thoughts?

I want my black image to show after the class changes!

Thanks if you can help!

Comment: Simplify your hasClass('') by only looking for a single class that determines the background. See if that changes your results. Also; have you checked the developer tools to see if the src attribute is changing for the element after this code runs?

Comment: When I simplify it to just look for one of the two, it defaults on 'navbar-transparent navbar-color-on-scroll fixed-top navbar-expand-lg' and uses whatever img is set to that

Comment: A few observations: Does hasClass even allow more than one class? In the docs it states classname but it says ELEMENTS can have more than one class but not being passed to it. Also, maybe not use navbar-transparent twice, and have the second one be something completely different and use the new one in hasclass.

Comment: Oh and the hasClass in your else doesn't do anything. Its within the else's function and not part of an elseif.

Answer (score 0):

1. You are repeating the same classes. You should add to one of them an UNIQUE CLASS in order to make it work.
2. The else dosen't need a condition.

If this the only element with .navbar-brand, it should be:

```
if ($('.navbar').hasClass('AN UNIQUE CLASS')) {
  $('.navbar-brand').attr('src','ZeusLogoWhite.png')
} 
else  { 
  $('.navbar-brand').attr('src','zeusAssistantBlackLogo.png')
 }
```

Hope that help.